Creating CSV string without plugin
I am trying to let the user download a list of filtered members from our app.
I've done a much more complicated CSV String which works fine but for some reason I cannot get this one to work.
The code is:
  function getCSVString(){
    return ['nom', 'telèfon', 'email'].join(',') + '\n'
    + filteredMembers.value.map(member => {
      return [member.nom, member.telèfon, member.email].join(',') + '\n'
    })
  }

I have tried so many variants, with some '\r\n' or the joins somewhere else, and downloaded 42 test files  already, but the closest I get looks like this, with a stupid white space after the first line that shifts everything:
Excel table with a stupid whitespace
What am I not seeing???
Thank you in advance!!!

Please provide a sample of filteredMembers.value so that we can see it "in action".  See [mcve].

Your code will fail if value is something like John Wick or John "Merciful" Wick - just few cases of invalid CSV produced. Why not use plugin that has already solved all issues that you don't even think exist?

also fail if any have a comma, eg, name = "John Wick, the third"

Tip: don't look at the result in Excel.  Look at the result in a text editor.  You'll see a leading comma on each line rather than a "stupid whitespace".   While this may not immediately help you, it's better to look at the output directly without a third-party app "interpreting" the result.

state the problem without unnecessary words in it.

Do you want the output as CSV or XLSX format? The image in your message is not a CSV output, it looks like an Excel sheet. In either case, for exporting data you can use SheetJS

@Haluk the screenshot is a csv opened in excel.

@fdomn-m, so do we need to understand that the user will use the CSV data in Excel? If so, names like John Wick, the third as you've already stated, will not be a problem when exported as an Excel file.

The screenshot is a CSV file opened in Numbers. I am trying to do without plugin because I'm a junior trying to learn, and will take the invalid values into consideration. I know it might fail but hey, my employers know I'm a junior, know it might fail, and still want to pay me. Might as well have fun.
Thanks for everyone's help!

@luluconcha, I applaud the effort to learn, but CSV is a real encoding scheme that takes some thought and care. There are plenty of tested and approved plugins that generate correct CSV. You run the risk of creating something that might work for a few, but not for others. StackOverflow has plenty of questions with the CSV tag of developers trying to decode an improperly encoded CSV, and most of the time that data is just corrupt. Please reconsider: use a CSV plugin and direct your learning efforts to something else.

NB: To highlight/repeat the comments for anyone viewing this in the future.   The below answers the question:

Why is there is an extra whitespace at the start of each row

This is not an fully fledged CSV export and should not be used in "real" code unless there's a known set of values (ie non-user input).
Anyone looking for CSV export code should consider all the rules required to build a functioning CSV, or look for an existing package/library.

Your issue is the .map is returning an array.
When you combine a str + array JS converts the array to a string representation, which is a comma-separated string - ie each line is comma separated - thus adding a comma at the start of each line.
Fix is to .join() the array returned by .map without commas


let members = [ 
    { nom:"A", tel:"1", email:"A" },
    { nom:"B", tel:"2", email:"B" },
    { nom:"C", tel:"3", email:"C" }
]
    
let result = ['nom', 'telèfon', 'email'].join(',') + '\n' +
  members.map(member => {
    return [member.nom, member.tel, member.email].join(',') + '\n'
  }).join("");

console.log(result);



An alternative is to remove the +'\n' from each line then the array/map .join("\n")


let members = [ 
    { nom:"A", tel:"1", email:"A" },
    { nom:"B", tel:"2", email:"B" },
    { nom:"C", tel:"3", email:"C" }
]
    
let result = ['nom', 'telèfon', 'email'].join(',') + '\n' +
  members.map(member => {
    return [member.nom, member.tel, member.email].join(',')
  }).join("\n");

console.log(result);




u/fdomn-m's answer solved it. I had tried with a .join(',') at the end but not .join(''). Thanks!

You could also remove the +'\n' in the map and then .join('\n') (which makes more sense to me - generate all the lines in an array then join them with a newline).

I did @fdomn-m, it does make more sense

This solution doesn't properly escape commas and double quotes. Please reconsider and encourage OP to use a validated and tested plugin.

@ZachYoung this has already been addressed multiple times in the comments.  SO isn't about providing the best final solution, it's about answering the question that has been asked.  So that OP (an already stated learner) can move on to the next stage (potentially a new question).  Guidance should not be above the answer OP is looking for (and accepted).

@ZachYoung does this answer answer the question of "why is there an extra space in the output", or not?  downvotes are for when the answer doesn't answer the question, not just because you don't like the question.

@fdomn-m, ah, I’m sorry, I didn’t see the specific issue of the misplaced white space; I focused on the title of the question and OP’s bigger intent. I’ve removed the downvote.

@ZachYoung no worries.  At your prompt, I added the extra info regarding it not being a full CSV solution.

@fdomn-m, cool!
